# TFS - Rolling average velocity in Velocity report

Tags: tfs, velocity, reportbuilder3.0

The TFS Scrum and Agile templates come with a Velocity report. It includes the story points completed for each sprint and an average velocity. After 27 sprints and various changes to the team, earlier results are no longer relevant to calculating our current velocity.
The average for the entire life of the project is calculated as

```
=Avg(Fields!Story_Points.Value, "dsVelocity")
```

How do I calculate the rolling average for the last 6 sprints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to calculate the average velocity for your team over the last several sprints. It's impossible by now. It will include all sprints.

As a workaround, you may need to calculate this manually. You can also add a feature request in User Voice Site: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: This answer was correct. I never did find a way to accomplish this directly. I could export to excel, but then you have to re-create the calculations every time. You could have a master sheet that included a detail sheet that is re-created each time, but this turns out to be fragile and in the end not worth the frustration.